# How to determine a successful share by addthis service

Tags: facebook-graph-api, share, addthis

One of my client wants to get some logic done on server side immediately after a member successfully share a link from his site. The problem is that some time member just open the share dialog by clicking the button and close it without sharing.
I was trying to use add eventListener to event type "addthis.menu.share" but this event get fired as soon as dialog is opened by clicking the service icon. It never determine whether a user really shared the link or just close the opened service dialog without sharing.
SO my question is there any way to know if a user has successfully shared the link immediately after sharing?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the services (FB, TW, G+, etc.) provide any type of callback/response that can be used to determine if the user actually shared the page.  This makes it impossible to know if the share actually occurred in realtime.  You can use either the APIs from the service like FB:

http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.addthis.com

To get the number of shares or you can use the Analytics API from AddThis:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381264-addthis-analytics-api#.UJqEWeOe_L4

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, Facebook's current APIs provide a callback when the content is shared, but i think addThis uses the old 'sharer.php' endpoint

Comment: Oh really, could you provide a link to the documentation for that?  I would be interested in seeing how it works.

Comment: sharer.php and/or the share button aren't in the current documentation, only the like button / feed dialog / send dialog are, those all have a callback you can subscribe to with [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)